# In AWS redshift, the json_extract_path_text function return empty string instead NU

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In AWS Redshift, I am using json_extract_path_text function to parse simple Json.
I deliberately try to find non exists element in the Json so the function should return NULL.
If I use the function in 'standalone' select, the function return NULL as expected but if the function is used in select from table then a string empty ("") returned.
Here a simple example:

```
select json_extract_path_text('{"A":"B"}', 'AA'); --> Return NULL as expected.

create table #test (
    payload varchar(max)
);
insert into #test (payload) values ('{"A":"B"}');

select json_extract_path_text(payload,'AA') from #test; --> Return empty string
```

[image]

[image]

How can I make the function return null from select table query?
Thanks.

I try everything...

Answer (score 1):

I posted to AWS the issue and they approved that this is a bug in Redshift:
AWS support:
"I have been in contact with our internal team and they mentioned that the inconsistency is actually a bug from Redshift side that is still being worked on by the Service team and will be addressed in the upcoming patches"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `NULLIF` function

```sql
select nullif(json_extract_path_text(payload,'AA'),'') from #test
```

Comment: When I try to cast it to json an error return: ERROR: type "json" does not exist

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, have edited the answer

Comment: thanks for you comment.
I already thought about it and it's not good. What if I have Json {"AA":""}? In this case I can't distinct between exists element with empty string and non exists element.

Comment: The `NULLIF` is applied on the result of the `json_extract_path_text` so it should not affect the input `JSON` string in anyway. You can give it a try to check if it causes any issues

Comment: Yes I know it's not affect on the source Json.
Take this Json: {"A":"B","C":""}. Now I want get element C. If it's empty I want to know about it. In this case I will get NULL and not "".
select nullif(json_extract_path_text(payload,'C'),'') from #test ==> return NULL.

Comment: The Redshift documentation says as follows `If a path element does not exist in the JSON string, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT returns an empty string.` but it also says this in the examples given below `If the JSON is valid, trying to extract an element that's missing returns NULL.`  [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) I would then suggest to get in touch with the AWS Support to check what's actually true

Comment: Ticket has been opened I will update soon.

Comment: @Idanb.y where you able to fix the above issue? can you share us the update from AWS guys?

Comment: @venkat, At that time AWS approved that is a bug in Redshift. Here is their (AWS) reply to my ticket: "I have been in contact with our internal team and they mentioned that the incosistency is actually a bug from Redshift side that is still being worked on by the Service team and will be addressed in the upcoming patches. Unfortunately, there isn’t an ETA as to when this will be fixed but usually new features and improvements in patch versions are typically announced in our below blogs and I would suggest you keep an eye on these."